# Teams: How can we set a a global notification for every new post in a specific channel?

Tags: microsoft-teams

in our company we use Microsoft Teams.
We have a team "All" and in it a channel "Broadcast".
How can we set it centrally so that all employees receive a notification when a new post is written?
Currently we write "@All" at the beginning of the text.
But I'm sure this can be done more elegantly.

I am looking forward to your tips.

Many thanks and greetings

Frank

Answer (score 0):

You can @mention the channel, so that all the members will get notified. You can achieve so using Graph API.

`POST` `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/channels/19:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@thread.tacv2/messages`

```
    {
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "Hello World <at id=\"0\">General</at>"
    },
    "mentions": [
        {
            "id": 0, 
            "mentionText": "General",
            "mentioned":  {
                        "conversation": {
                            "id": "19:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@thread.tacv2",
                            "displayName": "General",
                            "conversationIdentityType@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Teams.GraphSvc.conversationIdentityType",
                            "conversationIdentityType": "channel"
                        }
        }
    ]
}
```